# Errors with TLS 1.0 client connecting to my ASP .Net Core service

Tags: windows, https, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-2.2

TL;DR: how do I configure an ASP.Net Core service which:

- Is installed on Windows (7 and above, though I'm developing/testing on **Windows 10**)
- Serves data over HTTPS
- Uses a Self-signed SSL Certificate (clients will reside on the same local network as the service & be accessed via local hostname, so purchasing a cert is not practical)
- **Allows TLS1.0 clients to connect** (running on Windows XP, sadly)

I have no problems with the first 3 things, it's just the TLS 1.0 clients I have a problem with.

I don't believe it's a problem with my service, rather the Windows OS and/or the self-signed SSL Certificate.

The certificate is being generated via a wrapper around the CERTENROLLLib dll.  I can change how this is generated (key lengths and hash algorithms etc), but it's not (clearly) my area of expertise....

Multiple clients based on Windows 7 and up work fine, assuming they have the self-signed cert added as a trusted cert and/or are simply written to not reject this cert...

When clients (well, the only single client I have available to test with) supporting only TLS 1.0 try to connect, they get SSL errors, and I can see in my Windows 10 System Event logs this:

```
An TLS 1.0 connection request was received from a remote client application, 
but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are 
supported by the server. The TLS connection request has failed.
```

If I create a local client on my machine and force it to use only TLS 1.0 via:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Then my *local* client works fine... but then this is the machine on which the cert was generated, so it'll have available exactly the same list of ciphers etc. so this isn't a huge surprise..

I have followed various advice found online about ensuring my windows 10 install will accept TLS 1.0 connections, and believe it is set up to do so.

So I *think* that the problem is one of these:

- My windows machine will accept TLS1.0 connections, but doesn't have whatever form of encryption cipher the windows XP client is requesting so the two can't agree; or
- The Self-Signed Certificate is using some form of hash algorithm that the Windows XP client doesn't understand.

Does anyone have any idea which of these it's likely to be, or any suggestions for what hash algorithms etc. I should use in the cert if it's the latter?  Or if I'm way off and there's something else amiss....?

Thanks.

Comment: TLS 1.0 isn't really any better than having no SSL at all. This is not really something you should be looking to enable. Clients that can't support at least TLS 1.1 need to upgrade. Windows 7 will be dead by next year anyways, and XP has been dead for some time.

Comment: I agree. However the clients are bespoke hardware terminals which we cannot change... And to not support it puts us at a competitive disadvantage. My half-serious suggestion was actually to just use http for those terminals, and if anyone points out the lack of security just point out that tls 1.0 is really as bad as nothing anyway.. To hopefully pressure the manufacturers into upgrading.

Comment: The issue is that XP can't negotiate any AES-based cipher suites (it's *that* old) and as you determined the intersection between supported cipher suites is very small. It's also not guaranteed the top intersection will be used as it needs to take into account multiple aspects of the handshake. It also takes into account how you're calling the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Actual Problem

OK, I finally figured this out.  It was actually the certificate - but NOT cipher suite related (well, that may have been part of the initial problem, but it wasn't the final piece of the puzzle)

We had a third party service available which was accessible from the XP machine over SSL. There were a number of differences with this system (hosted on Win7/IIS Vs win10/Kestrel but after eliminating these (by eventually hosting a basic site on IIS/win 7 using different certs) I eventually found that it was simply the certificate.

Careful analysis of the one working cert vs. the self-signed ones we were generating revealed a number of differences:

- SHA-1 vs other, stronger encryption
- very limited other information (e.g. Subject/Issuer were simply the Hostname, no additional DNS stuff, etc.
- The 'Key Usage' part was marked as *critical* **on our self-signed certs, but *not* on the working one**

The last part appears to have been the real key to this.  When the cert had the 'Key Usage' extension marked as *critical* it simply wouldn't work.

What was very odd was that even when looking at the network traffic, you never saw the server actually sending the Certificate back to the client (usually all you'd see is the client sending `ClientHello` TLS packets), so I don't fully understand how this caused the issue, but it definitely was the cert.

## The Fix:

We were originally using c# code which wrapped around the 'CERTENROLLLib' Interop library to generate certificates.  It turns out there is a bug in this code somewhere, which meant even if these parts were *explicitly* defined as `Critical=false;` then they would *still* end up being flagged as *Critical*:

```cs
var keyUsageClass = new CX509ExtensionKeyUsageClass();
keyUsageClass.InitializeEncode(
      CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE_KEY_USAGE
      | CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE
      | CERTENROLLLib.X509KeyUsageFlags.XCN_CERT_DATA_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE
                );
//This appears to be IGNORED;  maybe fixed in some later version, no idea.
keyUsageClass.Critical = false;

...

cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(
  X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine, 
  privateKey, "");

cert.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)keyUsageClass);
```

In the end I simply used powershell.  This appears to still have the problem, but with the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdLet it is at least *possible* to specify a Key Usage of `None` (seems not possible via CertEnrollLib), which means this section is omitted entirely.

For reference, this is the section of powershell script I used, which creates the cert then saves it to a .pfx file for import on clients as 'trusted'

```bsh
#various vars to use in the create command
$certSubject = $env:computername
$certFriendlyName= "$($certSubject)_MyCert"
$certPfxFileName = "$($certFriendlyName).pfx"
$expiryDate = (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
$flagsForServerCert = "2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"
$certPassword = "somePassword123!"

#Note: this is one command, on one line, broken here for readability:
New-SelfSignedCertificate 
  -DNSName $certSubject 
  -FriendlyName $certFriendlyName 
  -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my 
  -subject $certSubject 
  -HashAlgorithm SHA 
  -NotAfter $expiryDate 
  -TextExtension $flagsForServerCert 
  -KeyUsage None

#Now we need to fetch the thumbprint of that cert.  note, multiple matching Certs will 
#mean this doesn't work, so ensure FriendlyName is unique in the first place.
$thumbprint=(Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localmachine\my | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -match $certFriendlyName}).Thumbprint

#Now to save as a pfx file, need to create a SecureString from the password.
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certPassword -Force -AsPlainText 

#Get the certificate, and pipe it through Export-PfxCertificate to save it.
Get-ChildItem -Path "cert:\localmachine\my\$($thumbprint)" | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certPfxFileName -Password $pwd
```

This then generated a Server cert which XP clients are happy with.